# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings reading only first key

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to read value from appSettings section of app.config file. I can't get why, but ConfigurationManager reading only first key (log4net.Internal.Debug), meanwhile I need another two keys. Here is appSettings.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
    <add key="SendGridUser" value="some value" />
    <add key="SendGridPassword" value="some value" />
  </appSettings>
```

Here is the code:

```
var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridUser"];
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridPassword"];
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or blank value?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. The problem is in the part of the code you are not showing us.

Comment: does it always read the first value?

Comment: Why do you think that manager is reading only first key?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, no, only null value. But when I see details in "Locals" panel, I can see only one key on index 0.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, when debugger comes to this line, on Locals I can see what's inside. So I can see only key on index 0 - log4net.Internal.Debug.

Comment: @RahulHendawe, this is Class Library, are you sure WebConfiguration will work there?

Comment: @andrey.shedko change the value that you can read in this file and check if you get the modified version. I bet you might be reading from different file. app.config is the file that in the runtime is copied to bin with modified name

Comment: Are you reading the app.config from the same project as the app.config is part of? Are you sure you do not have two app.config and the one which your code referz has three values?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, yes, I'm sure that this app.config belong to the project where is this code defined and yes, I'm sure that here is only one app.confirg per project.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik, look like you're right. At least - when I change key/value, I got same key/value that was there before.

Comment: then the provided answer by @sergey-berezovskiy is what you should look into. I would give the similar one

Answer (score 3):

If in debug mode you see only one key in `AppSettings` collection, then it means `ConfigurationManager` is not reading configuration file which you think it should read. Possible reasons:

- You don't have *'copy if newer'* or *'copy always'* selected for configuration file `Copy to Output Directory` setting. Thus file was not updated in build folder.
- There is [transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) on file for Debug build which removes some settings from config. Check whether you have `App.Debug.config` in solution explorer.

Comment: Certainly, there is no transformation on this particular app.config. You was right about Copy to Output Directory setting, but this didn't helped as well.

Comment: @andrey.shedko hmm try to rebuild solution and check what do you have in project build folder